# Ubuntu exce Maven Plugin

Tags: maven

I'm Running My Eclipse (Helios) in Ubuntu. I've added exec Maven Plug in. When i try to run Maven build I'm getting on IO Exception.

It's try to execute Java in my Project Directory, so Getting on IO Exception.
I've Set up My JAVA_HOME, MAVEN_HOME, still it try to run Java from my project Directory.

I've added my pom file & the exception.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>kilim-weave</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>

                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>

                <arguments>
                    <argument>-Dmyproperty=myvalue</argument>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath/>
                    <argument>kilim.tools.Weaver</argument>
                    <argument>-d</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}/com/contivo/smf</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "MY Project DIrectory"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:302)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:589)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:335)
    ... 21 more

is there any Configuration I'm missing.

Thanks in advance

Sathish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executable command Can be a full path or a the name executable. In the latter case, the executable must be in the PATH for the execution to work.

The plugin will search for the executable in the following order:

```
relative to the root of the project
as toolchain executable
relative to the working directory (Windows only)
relative to the directories specified in the system property PATH (Windows Only)
```

i've tried with full path, it works.

Answer (score 1):

[Put it in the PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) - Maven will behave much better if java and javac is in your PATH.

Comment: do you have any examples how to do this for this specific info?